# Getting a Python library listed in easy_setup and pip?

Tags: python

Every Python developer is familiar with easy_install and setup tools.

If I want to install a library that's well known, all I have to do is this:

sudo easy_setup install django

Now I have a library that I've written and would love to see widespread. How do you get added to this library list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Upload it to [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi). See the [tutorial](http://wiki.python.org/moin/CheeseShopTutorial).